# Can't open Widget from the MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I want to open a Widget from my MainWindow. I thought this was easy to do, and all the tutorials I read do it like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Types_clicked()
{
    m_typesWin = new TypesWindow(m_db, this);
    m_typesWin->show();
    this->hide();
}
```

However, this only works for me if I don't pass "this" into the constructor. When I add "this" to the constructor, I don't see the widget, the program just stops. If I don't hide "this", then I can see that parts of my widget are actually in my main window. I have no idea why.

EDIT: The classes are automatically created by QtCreator, so they should be alright.

Comment: Pardon me. What's `m_db`? Btw, if you didn't see your widget, try add `m_typesWin->raise();` and `m_typesWin->activateWindow();` after it showed.

Comment: You shouldn't pass parent window to top level windows. Top level windows are widgets without parents. (If you want to make TypesWindow a top level window, it shouldn't have another window as a parent)

Comment: @Lahiru Chandima: What exactly is a "top level window"?

Comment: @Tay2510: m_db is an object I need in the widget. Nothing important (I guess). I tried raise() and activateWindow() but that did not help. The widget still vanishes and the program shuts down.

Comment: Actually it should be corrected to a top level *widget*. Widget without a parent widget is a top level widget. Only top level widgets have their own window. Widgets having a parent widget are embedded in their parent widget's window

Comment: @Lahiru Chandima: I have a MainWindow and a Widget, so that widget is a top level widget then? But how can I access the MainWindow again, after closing the Widget?

Comment: Simply don't pass main window pointer to the parent class of TypesWindow in TypesWindow constructor. Store it in a pointer in TypesWindow itself.

Comment: Why do you use two mainwindows?

Comment: @lpapp: I don't think I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a QWidget to be displayed as a window, a parent widget should not be specified to that widget. Here, because you specify main window as the parent of TypesWindow, TypesWindow becomes embedded in main window. So when you hide main window, TypesWindow embedded in main window also gets hidden.

Since you want TypesWindow to be a separate window, don't pass parent widget to the QWidget constructor in TypesWindow constructor. If you want to access main window from TypesWindow, you can store main window pointer in a pointer field in TypesWindow.

Comment: Parent widget should be specified. Because it will keep clear pointer owning. Right solution is to set `Qt::Window` (or `Qt::Dialog`) flag.

Answer (score 0):

To open a Mainwindows from the new Qwidget:

1)in the NEWWIDGET.CPP:

```
QWidget *w;

NEWWIDGET::NEWWIDGET(QWidget *parent,QWidget *win) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::NEWWIDGET)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  w=win;
}

..

void NEWWIDGET::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  this->hide();
  w->show();
}
```

2)In the NEWWIDGET.H

```
public:
    explicit NEWWIDGET(QWidget *parent=nullptr,QWidget *win=nullptr);
    ~NEWWIDGET();
```